# New to React, first button works, second button's supposed to call its own function but seems to call the first function

Tags: reactjs

I'm sure I'm missing something foundational regarding React components but I can't seem to figure out why the first button works while the second button fails to call the function I assigned it to.

Intent:
Clicking on the first button results in a new company being added to the list
Clicking on the buttons next to the company names should delete that

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Faker/3.1.0/faker.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='root'></div>
    <script type='text/babel'>
      const { render } = ReactDOM;
      const { Component } = React;

      class App extends Component{
        constructor(){
          super();
          this.state = {
            companyList: ['Some Company']
          }
          this.clickFunction = this.clickFunction.bind(this)
          this.elimFunction = this.clickFunction.bind(this)
        }
        clickFunction() {
          const newCompany = faker.company.companyName()
          this.setState({ companyList: [...this.state.companyList, newCompany]})
        }

        elimFunction(cut) {
          const splice = this.state.companyList.splice(cut, 1)
          this.setState({ companyList: splice})
        }
  
        render(){
          return (
            <div>
              <button onClick={()=>{this.clickFunction()}}>  
                Click to add 
              </button> 
              <ul> 
                {
                  this.state.companyList.map((e,i)=>
                    <li key={i}> 
                      {e} <button onClick={()=>this.elimFunction({i})}> 
                      Delete</button>
                    </li> 
                  )
                }
              </ul> 
            </div> 
          )
        }
      }

      render(<App />, document.querySelector('#root'));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This version works BUT I'm also reading that I shouldn't have setState in render. I have it twice so I feel like I'm supposed to get crucified at this point. My interpretation of such bad practice could be wrong too. I'm open to suggestions.

```html
<!-- Adding and Removing Elements-->

<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Faker/3.1.0/faker.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">
      const { render } = ReactDOM;
      const { Component } = React;

      class App extends Component {
        constructor() {
          super();
          this.state = {
            list: ["someCompany"],
          };
        }
        render() {
          //This works but is not good practice to have render modify state 
          return (
            <div>
              <h1> Generate a new company</h1>
              <button onClick={() => {
                const newCompany = faker.company.companyName();
                this.setState({ list: [...this.state.list, newCompany] });
                }}>
                Add a company
              </button>
              {this.state.list.map((e, i) => (
                <li>
                  {e} 
                  <button onClick={() => {
                    this.state.list.splice(i, 1);
                    this.setState({ list: this.state.list });
                    }}>
                    Delete
                  </button>
                </li>))}
            </div>
          );
        }
      }

      render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.elimFunction = this.clickFunction.bind(this)
```

This should be this in constructor

```
this.elimFunction = this.elimFunction.bind(this)
```

Also elimFunction will be like this (To fix whole list deletion error):

```
  elimFunction(cut) { 
    var array = [...this.state.companyList]; 
    array.splice(cut.i, 1); 
    this.setState({ companyList: array }); 
}
```

Comment: I gave that a go. That was a silly mistake of me. But now that's taken care of, instead of deleting just one entry. It's deleting the whole list.

EDIT: I'm slowly console logging the different parts of elimFunction to see what's going on. I see that i is being in successfully at the least.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-gsamaj Fixed the whole list deletion error

Comment: elimFunction(cut) {
          var array = [...this.state.companyList];
          array.splice(cut.i, 1);

          this.setState({ companyList: array });
        }

Comment: Thats's how elim function will loook. Problem was cut was an object. So we refer cut.i. And array splice mutates array and returns single element. Splice returns the deleted elements and the code was setting the return value not mutated array . Refer this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice#return_value

Hope this helps! Let me know if you face any other trouble.

Comment: This helped a lot. I forgot what splice essentially did so it's no wonder I was only getting one value each time I console logged it. Then that part about how 'i' was passed in. I'm still getting used to JSX and how it jumps in and out of curly brackets.  This exercise and your solution helped tremendously. I wish I could upvote but I don't have enough rep points yet. When I do, I'll be sure to return. Thank you again.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I looked at the link and have accepted your solution. Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

It was a slight of hand mistake @Ken as @Siddharth has pointed out.

Also, there's another way to bind functions besides `.bind`. You write your class function as an arrow function, and it will auto-bind. It saves you an extra line of code.

Before

```
this.clickFunction = this.clickFunction.bind(this)
...
clickFunction() {
          const newCompany = faker.company.companyName()
          ...
        }
```

After

```
clickFunction = () => {
          const newCompany = faker.company.companyName()
          ...
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for this. That would make the code look a lot cleaner. Just curious though, would 'this' act differently in that arrow function then such as when I call setState. I normally use this.setState({key:value})

Comment: Arrow functions do not have a `this` variable that refers to itself like a regular function.
If `this` is used inside of an arrow function, it will reference its closest parent, in this case, the class. So `this.setState` will work as expected.